# Updating the user coming from react-with-firebase-auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I built an app starting from a super easy [example on medium](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-setup-firebase-authentication-with-react-in-5-minutes-maybe-10-bb8bb53e8834).

To summarize, it appears the user comes into my app at the bottom part. I then pass the user down through props:

```
function App({user)){
 return <AppContainer user={users} />
}
export default withFirebaseAuth({
  providers,
  firebaseAppAuth,
})(App);
```

Later in my app  I want to update the user:

```
function AppContainer( { signOut, user } ){
  const [user, setUser] = useState(user);

  firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      setUser(doc.data())
```

But it doesn't work. What's the Best way to do this?

Additionally it would be ideal if the two API calls could be combined somehow.

Last question is - I don't really understand how the export part of the code works - is it like context and i should be able to access the data coming in as props all the way down? Can I refactor it into context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually for similar API calls [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook is used, as documentation states:

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of `useEffect` Hook as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` combined.

First I would add the **firebase** calls into that hook then secondly I would change the `user` variable's name, you have one coming through props and similarly you are defining with `useState`.

I would consider using as the following:

```
function AppContainer( { signOut, user } ){
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(user);

  useEffect(() => {
     firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            setUser(doc.data());
        }
     });
  }, []);
```

At the end, you will have the returned user information from **firebase** in `currentUser` state object.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you,
 I considered that but... it seems not ideal.  Ideally i would:
1. Get the whole user in one call from firebase
2. Merge the two objects (?)